# Easier way to remember trace flags in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Apart from memorizing what every [trace flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx) does, is there an easy way to remember what groups of trace flags do.   The first digit of the trace flag number looks like it may mean something?

Does anyone know what this first digit denotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the trace flags are grouped by area of SQL Server - the first two digits always denote the area. For example:

- 6xx are Storage Engine access methods
- 8xx are buffer pool
- 12xx are lock manager
- 14xx are database mirroring
- 25xx, 52xx are DBCC related
- 30xx, 31xx, 32xx are backup/restore
- 36xx are SQL Server general 'run-time'
- 55xx are FILESTREAM
- 73xx, 74xx are query execution
- 76xx are full text related (?)
- 75xx are cursors
- 82xx are replication

These are just the ones I remember as I don't have source code any more (I wrote a bunch of the code and owned the whoe Storage Engine for 2008).

There's no easy way to remember what each one does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Paul, I'm disappointed.  You don't have the entire source code for SQL memorized?

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Paul has posted, you can google for most trace flags and get a description of them.  Even a lot of the undocumented ones are out there.  Most of the trace flags which are documented that you'll need to use all the often will be available in Books OnLine.